# GetOpt doesn't read full URL

Tags: php, bash

I have a script that need to run from a terminal or a command prompt. I'm using PHP. `GetOpt` is the function that I use to get data or a parameter that the user input in the terminal.

This is my script.

```
<?php
$opt = getopt("f:");
$input = $opt['f'];
$u = fopen($input, 'r');
echo "\n\n$input\n\n";
```

I tried to run it like this:

```
$ php myscript.php -f http://myurl.com/file.csv?city=london&status=3
```

My url is `http://myurl.com/file.csv?city=london&status=3`, but it only outputs  `http://myurl.com/file.csv?city=london`. The status parameter is lost from the full URL.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have to wrap your link around into quotes:

```
$ php myscript.php -f "http://myurl.com/file.csv?city=london&status=3"
```

I'll go ahead and assume you are running your script in Bash, and `&` in Bash might be interpreted as bitwise `AND` in your case:

```
$ echo $(( 98 & 7 ))
2
```

Comment: nice. do you have idea that make the url converted into quote? "$input" ?

Comment: @IWayanDharmana it's something what you manually type in bash, is it not? If not, it's a matter for another question.